# C# Why can I access a non static class' methods and properties via a property, without creating an instance of that class first?

Tags: c#, oop, methods

I am very new to C# and have been doing a series of fundamentals training courses in C# and .NET Core. During these courses, I have been continually told that unless a class is static, I have to create a new instance of a class via the 'new' keyword to access its properties and methods. However, on one training course (.NET Core fundamentals) there is an example that is not explained where this does not appear to be the case and I need help to understand why.

On the course there are two classes 'Restaurant' and 'DetailModel'. All methods and properties within the Restaurant class are public, the Restaurant class and its properties and methods are not static. In the DetailModel class (housed in a separate class file), a new property is created called Restaurant with a type of Restaurant like so:

```
public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
```

Via this property, I can now access all of the methods and properties of the Restaurant class without creating a new instance of the Restaurant class. My question is, when I have been constantly told that you cannot access a non-static class' methods and properties without creating a new instance of that class, why am I allowed to set up a property with the type of that class and then access that class'  methods and properties that way, without creating a new object of that class via the 'new keyword? Any help would be much appreciated.

The version of the .NET Core framework I am using is 2.2.

See the code for both simplified classes below:

```
public class Restaurant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public CusineType Cuisine { get; set; }

    }

 public class DetailModel : PageModel
    {

        public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Restaurant.Name = "Test Restaurant";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cant see you, as a human but knowing you are human I can assume you have hands, feet and a head.. so the same is true with classes you specified the variable is of a type which has those properties, if filled then those properties exist, you will of course get a nullexception error if you try to use them when its not filled

Comment: In the example you are not accessing the class's Name property but your object that is a property. But if you run just this code it will throw a NullReferenceException because it hasn't been initialized yet (in the examle). Maybe some initialization outside or inside the class. In visual studio you can right click to the property and click to **Find all reference** that will show you what uses that particular variable/property.

Comment: I think it is less confusing if you don't name the property the same as the type. With `public Restaurant MyRest {get;set;}` you see that `MyRest.Name` is _not_ accessing a static property of the type, but an instance property of `MyRest` instance. That this instance is currently probably `null` is a different problem.

Comment: Run the code and you´ll see that you get a NullReferenceException, exactly because there is no `Restaurant` created - the property has not been set.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help especially @René Vogt, It has really clarified what is going on for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the property definition:

```
public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
```

This is the instance of the class Restaurant, that is also called Restaurant.

In this line

```
Restaurant.Name = "Test Restaurant";
```

you are not accessing the property of the class, but of the instance. Rename the instance to RestaurantInstance if you want to see what I'm talking about.

The actual instance of Restaurant class will be created on instantiation of DetailModel class. Its default constructor will create Restaurant as null, not as new Restaurant().

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is the fact that in `DetailModel` there is a property of type `Restaurant` that's also called `Restaurant`. The line

```
Restaurant.Name = "Test Restaurant";
```

refers to that property. For clarity, you can imagine a `this` in front of `Restaurant` like so:

```
this.Restaurant.Name = "Test Restaurant";
```

Naming properties the same as the class they're from can be confusing and should be avoided if possible (this often happens with color-properties that are of type `Color` and also named `Color`).

Note: for the setting of the name to work, the property needs to be initialised somewhere before (that's the `new Restaurant()` that you were expecting).